# why the XHR show js load request in Google Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Now I am using google chrome to debbugging my website, and now the js load request shows in XHR tab:

[image]

why the XHR show js request? how to make it only show the XHR request in Google Chrome DevTools?

Comment: yes, I am using react and hot reload. @zero298

Comment: Those are still XHR requests, they are just made to a JS resource.